# Embed Plotly graph into a webpage with Bottle

Tags: python, bottle, plotly

Hi i am using plotly to generate graphs using Python, Bottle. However, this returns me a url. 
Like:

```
https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1
```

I want to paste the entire graph into my webpage instead of providing a link. Is this possible?

My code is:

```
import os
from bottle import run, template, get, post, request
from plotly import plotly

py = plotly(username='user', key='key')

@get('/plot')
def form():
    return '''<h2>Graph via Plot.ly</h2>
              <form method="POST" action="/plot">
                Name: <input name="name1" type="text" />
                Age: <input name="age1" type="text" /><br/>
                Name: <input name="name2" type="text" />
                Age: <input name="age2" type="text" /><br/>
                Name: <input name="name3" type="text" />
                Age: <input name="age3" type="text" /><br/>                
                <input type="submit" />
              </form>'''

@post('/plot')
def submit():
    name1   = request.forms.get('name1')
    age1    = request.forms.get('age1')
    name2   = request.forms.get('name2')
    age2    = request.forms.get('age2')
    name3   = request.forms.get('name3')
    age3    = request.forms.get('age3')

    x0 = [name1, name2, name3];
    y0 = [age1, age2, age3];
    data = {'x': x0, 'y': y0, 'type': 'bar'}
    response = py.plot([data])
    url = response['url']
    filename = response['filename']
    return ('''Congrats! View your chart here <a href="https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1">View Graph</a>!''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080))
    run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: Ever considered using templates in flask?

Comment: i had templates. But how would it help?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, embedding is possible. Here's an iframe snippet you can use (with any Plotly URL):

`<iframe width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src="https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1/.embed?width=800&height=600"></iframe>`

The plot gets embedded at a URL that is made especially for embedding the plot. So in this case your plot is https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1/. The URL to embed it is made by adding .embed to the URL: https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1.embed.

You can change the width/height dimensions in that snippet. To get the iframe code and see different sizes, you can click the embed icon on a plot, or when you share it generate the code. Here's where the embed options are:

[image]

[Here's how an embedded graph looks in the Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/wonkblog/wp/2013/06/14/do-low-taxes-on-the-rich-leave-the-middle-class-with-lower-wages/). And [here](https://realpython.com/blog/python/developing-with-bottle-part-2-plot-ly-api/) is a helpful tutorial someone made on developing with Plotly and Bottle.

Let me know if that doesn't work, and I'm happy to help out.

Disclosure: I'm on the Plotly team.

Comment: I am looking for something similar. My situation is to run a python code after interval of every 5 mins and update the same plot. Instead I am getting new window every time. I am trying to embed the iframe of webpage so need to update the same plot. I have like 20 such plots.

Comment: The plotly URL comes from the API, right? Is there a way to do something like this with the recently published offline libraries?